# Temporale Präpositionen

Tags: preposition, grammar-identification

> Wie lange lernst du schon Deutsch?
>
> a. Seit 14
>      b. Über 3 Jahre
>      c. Seit 4 Jahren
>      d. Für 14 Jahre
>      e. Von 14 Jahren an

What is the answer to this question?

---

I checked b and e. But the answer is e and I want to know why b is not the answer.

Comment: Well, what do you think? I suggest you amend the question, documenting your own efforts.

Comment: We are not doing your homework. I can't see your efforts. Tell us what you think is right or wrong, and tell us why you believe this. Then we will give you some feedback.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake:( I didn't write my answer. I check b and e. But the answer is e and I want to know why b is not the answer.

Comment: Hi 안형서, please edit your question and include your comments there with the "edit" button below your answer. Is "Jaren" in answer C a spelling mistake you made or is the spelling mistake in the original answer too?

Comment: What is the intended meaning? The person has been learning for x years? That person started learning at the age of y?

Comment: If your book says *e* is the answer, throw it in the trash bin.

Answer (score 4):

Formally, the proposition to be used is "seit", so the answer should be one of those:

> (1) Seit 4 Jahren.
>
> (2) Seit über 3 Jahren. / Seit mehr als 3 Jahren.
>
> (3) Seit ich 14 war (or: bin). / Seit meinem 14. Lebensjahr.

Slightly more colloquially, for (1) and (2), "seit" + Dat. can be replaced by Akk.:

> (1) 4 Jahre.
>
> (2) Über 3 Jahre. / Mehr als 3 Jahre.

Note that this works only if a time interval is specified (1, 2), but not if a starting point is specified (3).

Answer (score 2):

Um ... others here are quite strict, I'm not. ;-)

a) can become possible if you specify the time designation. -> *seit 14 Tagen / Wochen / Monaten / Jahren*

b) is rather colloquial, but acceptable. *seit mehr als 3 Jahren* would be perfect

c) is fine if you add the missing '*h*' in * *Jaren*

d) is completeley ungrammatical. It very much looks like an unqualified translation of 'I've lived here for 14 years' which in German must be: *... (schon) seit 14 Jahren*

e) is what we call 'kommunikativ' which means: we understand it, but it's not correct. You'd better say: *seit meinem 14. Lebensjahr* which, however, is somewhat stilted. The exit is: *seit der 8. Klasse* :-)

Cheers!

Comment: *Über* is not actually a replacement for *seit*, but denotes *longer than*, so *seit* is still required.

Comment: In reference to your critique of Hubert's *we*: Who is *we* your sentence "what we call 'kommunikativ'"? Because "kommunikativ sein" is something different than "sich verständlich machen können"!

Answer (score 2):

Interpreting your question strictly literally, the only grammatically correct answer is "b"

> Wie lange lernst du schon Deutsch?
>
> Über 3 Jahre.

All other answers have issues - on different levels:

> *Seit 14.

could be used in a very sloppy oral conversation. It would then be understood as "Seit ich 14 Jahre alt bin". But the answer is too abbreviated to be used in more formal communciation, especially in written texts.

> *Seit 4 Jaren.

has simply a spelling error. Written as "Seit 4 Jahren" it would be alright.

> *Für 14 Jahre.

is nothing native speakers would say. It seems to be inspired by the English "I have been learning Bulgarian *for 14 years*".

> *Von 14 Jahre an.

again has a spelling error/morphological error. "Von 14 Jahren an" (with an n) could be a valid answer, although still a bit unusual.

Note that I added a period to each answer. This is to indicate that the utterance should be understood as a "full sentence" (according to the thought process of the speaker, not in terms of traditional grammar where a full sentence needs a verb.)

Comment: Das ist zwar eine richtige, aber nicht hilfreiche Antwort. Willst du den OP verwirren oder ihm helfen?

Comment: @tofro  Die Frage war unklar gestellt (wie ja auch viele Kommentierer bemängelt haben). Ich habe mich darum mit der Antwort auf das beschränkt, was bei der unklaren Frage klarerweise gesagt werden konnte. - Inzwischen wurde die Frage nun etwas verbessert, darum ist vielleicht meine Antwort nicht mehr so punktgenau.